# Is it possible to reference enum from another class via a shortcut?

Tags: c#, enums, reference

So I have an enum like this:

```
public class MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName : AbstractModel, IPerforceModule
{
    public enum Status { Fatal, Priority, Error, Warning, Info, Debug }
```

and when I access the enum in another class I have to do so like:

```
MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName.Status state = MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName.Status.Fatal
```

What im trying to do is like link to this enum in my other class so I can skip the long class name.. something like this pseudocode:

```
public class MyOtherClass : AbstractModel, IFileBrowser
{
    private enum Status = MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName.Status
    Status state = Status.Fatal;
    (state == MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName.Status.Fatal) //true
```

Any way this could be done in C#?

Comment: Closest you can do is define alias (but not inside `MyOtherClass` - on top of .cs file in which that class resides): `using Status = MyNamespace.MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName.Status;`

Comment: yep, alias did it, exactly what I need. Youre right this is probably a duplicate of the alias class name question, I just wasnt sure what doing this is called (alias) so was hard to search for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created an enum in the scope of the class. Simply move the enum out so 'it stands on its own' inside the namespace:

```
public enum Status { Fatal, Priority, Error, Warning, Info, Debug }

public class MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName : AbstractModel, IPerforceModule
{
```

Another way would be to create an `using`:

```
using Short = NameSpace.MyObnoxiouslyLongClassName.Status;
```

The downside of the latter is that you have to repeat the using in every class you intend to use it.

Comment: Thanks, these worked.